# Ubuntu 18: How to add a new HDD disk?

Tags: hard-drive, disk

Today I installed Ubuntu 18 at my SSD, but I also have plugged my second HDD with old windows files (music, games etc). I don't wanna format this disk to keep all my files and games.

**And now my question is:**
How can I add this disk to a Linux system as a secondary disk?
My Ubuntu see this disk in "other location" as "new volume", I can explore files but some programs cannot see this HDD. I wish to use Wine for play my windows games.

Comment: If used with Windows is hibernation flag still set. Windows fast start up sets that flag and then the Linux NTFS driver will not mount it.Unless you have Windows you should not use NTFS as it will need chkdsk and defrag and you cannot do those from Linux. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I don't have windows anymore on my PC, I have only ubuntu but the second HDD I used on windows before. I don't wanna format this because I will keep my files there, ubuntu see this HDD but I think it see it as removable memory or something like that, I can explore files there and open everything, just I want my system to show it like a normal disk

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a mountpoint directory for your hdd:

   `sudo mkdir /media/hdd2`
2. Run `sudo blkid`, get the UUID of the `/dev/sdZX` partition and add it to `/etc/fstab` (make backup of fstab befor modifying it):
3. Add a line to `/etc/fstab`

   `UUID="XXXXXXXXXXXX"  /media/hdd2  ntfs-3g  permissions,defaults  0  2`
4. Mount it to test:

   `mount -av`

If you get an error like `Failed to mount '/dev/sdZX': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state.` it means a "non-complete" shutdown on this drive and you must run Windows on it...

5. Take ownership of the drive

   `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/hdd2`